Force MS Teams chatbot to ask for new Graph permissions
I have developed a Microsoft Teams chatbot, that asks the connected user for some permissions to access some of his Microsoft Graph data. This is the code to do it, which works fine:
var oAuthPromptSettings = new OAuthPromptSettings
{
    ConnectionName = generalAppSettingsModel.Value.MsGraphConnectionName,
    Text = Localizer.GetString(LocalizationConstants.MS_GRAPH_CONNECTION_MESSAGE).Value,
    Title = Localizer.GetString(LocalizationConstants.AUTHORIZE_MESSAGE).Value,
};

AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(nameof(OAuthPrompt), oAuthPromptSettings));


My problem is that now I have changed the required permissions, to add a new one. It works fine for new users that were never asked to grant permissions, but users that had previously granted permissions are not asked again for the new one.
How can I invalidate the granted permissions so that every user is asked again for the new list of permissions?

You can revoke the existing tokens for the users. This will force them to go through the OAuth flow again and grant the new permissions. You can use the Microsoft Graph API to revoke the tokens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
